# Can verify certificate only with intermediate and root certificate in one file

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have two certificates sent by server during SSL handshake, domain certificate and intermediate certificate signed by `DigiCert Global Root CA`. I can verify the intermediate certificate

```
# openssl verify intermediate.pem
cert2.pem: OK
```

but not the domain cert

```
# openssl verify -CAfile intermediate.pem domain.pem
cert1.pem: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

`DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA` is the intermediate certificate. Verification works when I concatenate both intermediate and root certificate

```
# openssl verify -CAfile combined.pem cert1.pem
cert1.pem: OK
```

The root certificate is present in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. The problem appears only on docker container (basing on centos 7), on host it works with no problems. Because of this validation problem SSL handshake fails and the connection with server is dropped. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# openssl verify -CAfile intermediate.pem domain.pem
cert1.pem: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

openssl expects to build the trust chain until the trusted root certificate. An intermediate certificate might be trusted but is not a root certificate (not self-signed). This means that by default the verification will fail if no root certificate is provided.

There is an option `-partial_chain` in newer versions of `openssl verify` which allows the verification to succeed when it ends in a trusted certificate even if this is not a root certificate. There is a similar option `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` in the OpenSSL library. But this needs to be explicitly enabled by the application, i.e. it is off by default.

> The root certificate is present in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt. The problem appears only on docker container (basing on centos 7), on host it works with no problems. Because of this validation problem SSL handshake fails and the connection with server is dropped. What can I do to fix this issue?

Unfortunately it is not clear if the root certificate is a) in the docker container too, b) what kind of application you have in the container and what code is used to verify the certificates and c) if the server application properly provides all intermediate certificates as it should. In other words: what you see with `openssl verify` might have nothing to do with what your experience with your unknown application.